# Php keyword search in file name in a directory and download

Tags: php, mysql

I have a list of files in a directory of some local path with names like `APX-904-118000945-NMR-ETC` with different extensions. For every file name a code exists, in this filename `118000945`, using which i want to search and download that file in php.

I am able to pass the code `i.e., 118000945` but unable to search for it and download with some piece of code got from web.

Could you help me out in writing a php script for this?

Comment: Haave a look at the glob() (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [symfony finder component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/finder.html)

```php
$idToFind = '118000945';

$finder = new Finder();
$finder->files()
    ->in('/path/to/dir')
    ->name(sprintf('*%s*', $idToFind));

foreach ($finder as $file) {
    $absoluteFilePath = $file->getRealPath();
    $fileNameWithExtension = $file->getRelativePathname();

    // ...
}
```

Comment: My code is not class based... I am able to search through the directory for the particular file but unable to search in file names for a particular string as my keyword will be a part of that file name

Comment: You can use the package above as long as you can install a composer package.